# How to select specific rows in pandas df based on and delete all other rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe made by merging two dataframes like this, to find the nearest df_diatom age to df_counting age.

```
merged=pd.merge_asof(diatoms, counting, left_on='Age_ka',right_on='age_med_Ka',direction='nearest')
```

It creates a dataframe like this:
[image: Image of merged dataframe where ages in the second age column repeat more than once]

I would like to write code to go through the ages, and delete any rows where |Age_ka - age_med_Ka| ≤ 0.5. Can anyone advise?

Comment: This question is most likely a duplicated. It's not really necessary to add another and self-answer it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here and don't know what posting etiquette is. Should I delete it?

Comment: Yes you should probably delete it.

Answer (score 1):

```
merged3=merged.loc[abs(merged['Age_ka']-merged['age_med_Ka']) <= 0.5]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).